# django forms exclude values from choicefield

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following model

```
class ActionConfirm(models.Model):
    CONFIRM_METHOD =  (
        (u'ce', u'Certificate'),
        (u'tf', u'Trainee Feedback'),
        (u'ms', u'Multi Source Feedback'),
        (u'rp', u'Reflection upon Practice'),
        (u'ot', u'Other - Please add/describe')
    )

    confirm_method = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CONFIRM_METHOD)
    user = User
```

and the following form

```
class ActionConfirmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ActionConfirm
```

and I know that I can get their current choices by doing

```
selected = ActionConfirm.objects.filter(user=user)
```

So how do I exclude values from the the confirm_method field which they have already selected?

If it was from a db I know I could do `choices = ActionConfirm.objects.exclude(choice__in =  selected)` but I don't know how to do it when it is from a tuple of tuples.

Comment: Just to clarify - are you trying to make it so users can only create `ActionConfirm` instances with `confirm_method` values that *they* have not used for previously created `ActionConfirm` instances?

Comment: Yeah thats right.  I haven't put all the fields in the ActionConfirm model above.  There is also a user field and the selected  = should have been ActionConfirm.objects.filter(user=user) not ConfirmChoices. Should be updated now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show the relationship between `ActionConfirm` and `ConfirmChoices`. Why is `confirm_method` a CharField rather than a ForeignKey?

However, if you can get the selected choices, you can exclude them in the `__init__` of the form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ActionConfirmForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    selected_choices = whatever
    self.fields['confirm_method'].choices = [(k, v) for k, v in CONFIRM_METHOD
                                             if k not in selected_choices]
```

Comment: `confirm_method` is a CharField because it's a tuple (`CONFIRM_METHOD`) with two-character "keys", rather than a reference to a separate model.

Comment: @Dominic yes, I was confused by the (now-removed) reference to a `ConfirmChoices` model.

Comment: Hi there @DanielRoseman. I've done quite similar to what you have said since I am having the same similar problem. But I need to know if im doing it correctly. Can you have a look. Ill highly appreciate it. here's the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603479/django-forms-exclude-values-from-choicefield-that-are-already-into-database